# Laravel 5.8 pusher private channel returns 403 forbidden error

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm trying to make Laravel 5.8 real time chat using pusher. Messages are successfully sending to pusher. Now I want to console.log pusher sended message, but I'm getting http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 forbidden error. Tried to change **BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

from

```
Broadcast::routes();
```

to

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

But after that I'm getting http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my **BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

**resources/js/bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,
});
```

**ChatEvent.php**

```
public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat');
    }
```

**resources/js/app.js**

```
mounted() {
        Echo.private('chat')
            .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
    }
```

**channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel("chat", function(){
    return true;
});
```